# How to filter None's out of List[Option]?

Tags: scala, scala-option

If I have a `List[Option[A]]` in Scala, what is the idiomatic way to filter out the `None` values?

One way is to use the following:

```
val someList: List[Option[String]] = List(Some("Hello"), None, Some("Goodbye"))
someList.filter(_ != None)
```

Is there a more "idiomatic" way? This does seem pretty simple.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730842/how-to-transform-scala-collection-of-optionx-to-collection-of-x

Answer (score 193, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the options at the same time, you can use `flatten`:

```
scala> someList.flatten
res0: List[String] = List(Hello, Goodbye)
```

Comment: I would add that `flatMap` can be used to process the list elements other than `None`s, similar to `someList.flatten.map`, as one often wants to work with these elements and not just `flatten` the list out of fun.

Comment: Yes, I hesitated to ask Raph what he's expecting to do with the filtered list. But there are also a lot of scenarios where you just want to flatten.

Comment: Sometimes I want to retrieve the contents of the `Option` objects, but other times I need them to remain as `Option[A]`. I am finding more and more uses for `Option[A]` -- cool feature.

Comment: Is there an equivalent flatForeach type method?

Comment: If you're collection is immutable, faltmap will do the trick. If you're collection is mutable, no, there is not.

Comment: I find that in some cases this requires the use of type ascription in order to work.

Comment: @cdmckay Just someList.flatten.foreach

Comment: @Frank  I think`flatMap` behaves like `map.flatten` rather then `flatten.map`. As if the map function return `None`, it will remove from final result.

Comment: `someList.iterator.flatten.foreach` avoids creating an intermediate strict list (as `someList.flatten.foreach` would).

Answer (score 22):

`someList.filter(_.isDefined)` if you want to keep the result type as `List[Option[A]]`

Answer (score 5):

The `cats` library also has `flattenOption`, which turns any `F[Option[A]]` into an `F[A]` (where `F[_]` is a `FunctorFilter`)

```
import cats.implicits._

List(Some(1), Some(2), None).flattenOption == List(1, 2)
```

Comment: Why would cats add this when flatten in the std lib does the job? Is it doing something extra?

Comment: @Mojo the cats version is more generic, as it provides this for any type, for which a `FunctorFilter` typeclass can be defined (e.g. cats provides such an instance for maps, so you can use it on a `Map[A, Option[B]`, which does not have `flatten` in the standard library)

Answer (score 0):

If you had a list of options of an object which is more complex than a string like so:

```scala
case class Thing(name: String, number: Int)

val someSequence: Seq[Option[Thing]] = Seq(
  Some(Thing("Hello", 1)),
  None,
  Some(Thing("Goodbye", 2)),
  None
)
```

you can use flatMap to chain the mapping of the inner value:

```scala
scala> someSequence.flatMap(_.map(_.name))
val res2: Seq[String] = List(Hello, Goodbye)
```

But in my opinion @Nicolas' answer above is cleaner because you would be able to do:

```scala
scala> someSequence.flatten.map(_.name)
val res3: Seq[String] = List(Hello, Goodbye)
```