# Scala: Filtering List of case class with fields of Option

Tags: scala

I have a `List[A]` where `A` is a case class with a number of fields, from which `x` and `y` are `Option[double]`. I am trying to filter this list based on two conditions as below:

```
val resFiltered = res.filter(c => (c.x.getOrElse(num) != num) && 
                                  (c.y.getOrElse(num) != num)
                             )
```

where `num` is really a random number. I am basically filtering the list to get rid of `A`s that either fields of `x` or `y` are null. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Thanks.

Based on my search, [this flatten approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104558/how-to-filter-nones-out-of-listoption) can be useful, but it doesn't support the fields.

Comment: You mean both fields should be not empty? Or it's enough one field is not empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say `x` and `y` are `Option[Double]` so they can't be null. It looks like this is what your code does...

```
.filter(c => c.x.nonEmpty || c.y.nonEmpty)
```

...but you state that you want to "get rid of" if "either field...", which might mean that `&&` should be used instead of `||`.

Comment: You're right. Edited the question and used `&&` instead of `||`