# Idiomatic way of prepending Option[A] to Option[List[A]]

Tags: scala

I have: `ox: Option[A]` and `oxs: Option[List[A]]`.

I would like to:

- Return `ox.get :: oxs.get` if both existed.
- Return `List(ox.get)` if `ox` existed and `oxs` did not.
- Return `oxs.get` if `oxs` existed and `ox` did not.
- Return `List()` if both are `None`.

I can achieve this with `if`s and `matches`. I was just wondering if there was any elegant idiomatic way of doing it?

EDIT: I have tested: `List(ox.map(List(_)), oxs).flatten.flatten` and it seems to work for all four cases, but it still looks a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Did you try `flatten` ? prolly this may help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730842/how-to-transform-scala-collection-of-optionx-to-collection-of-x/4730888#4730888

Comment: @Shrey: I tried `List(ox.map(List(_)), oxs).flatten.flatten`. Although the type I get as a result matches, it seems too crazy to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val oa: Option[A] = ???
val oas: Option[List[A]] = ???

val result = oa ++: oas.getOrElse( Nil ) // O(1).
val result2 = oa ++: oas.flatten // 2.9.x only. same result, less performance (O(N)).
val result3 = oa ++: oas.toList.flatten // 2.10.x. O(N).
```

Flatten creates new `List` in `result2` while `result` reuses initial list:

```
val oa = Some(1)
val as = List(2,3)
val oas = Option(as)

val result = oa ++: oas.getOrElse( Nil )
// List(1, 2, 3)

val result2 = oa ++: oas.flatten
// List(1, 2, 3)

result.tail eq as // true - same object

result2.tail eq as // false - new object
```

Comment: Although result2 may have less performance, I like it from a readability point of view (my lists will be short and this operation will be outside a critical loop)

Comment: Thanks! It is really amazing how powerful and expressive FP can be.

Answer (score 7):

Try,

```
ox.toList ++ oxs.toList.flatten
```

And if you don't mind the result being an `Iterable[Int]` rather than a `List[Int]` you can drop the initial `toList`,

```
ox ++ oxs.toList.flatten
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason to mention `toList` before `flatten` explicitly?

Comment: @senia `flatten` is available on `List[List[T]]` but not on `Option[List[T]]`.

Comment: @MilesSabin there is an implicit `Option.option2Iterable`.

Comment: @senia There is, but it's not applicable because there is a `flatten` method defined directly on `Option`. This is turn is not applicable because it require evidence that the content of the `Option` is itself an `Option`. Don't believe me? Give it a try: `scala> Option(List(1, 2, 3)).flatten` yields `error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< Option[B]`.

Comment: @MilesSabin: thank you. I've tested only on `2.9.3` and there is no `flatten` method in `Option` in `2.9.3`.

Comment: @senia Well remembered ... yes, on 2.9.x the second `toList` can be dropped.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a for comprehension:

```
for (x <- ox; xs <- oxs) yield x :: xs
```

which is just a nicer way of writing

```
ox.flatMap(x => oxs.map(xs => x :: xs))
```

Comment: The for comprehension only works in the case both are not `None`.