# Scala: List of Option tuples in a map

Tags: scala

I have a List of values that could be `None`

`val list = List(("apples",1), ("oranges",3), ("avocado",4), None, ("pears",10))`

how can i transform this into a Map like :

`Map("apples"->1, "oranges"->3, "avocado"->4, "pears"->10)`

that skips the null elements?

I can't use a `toMap` to `list` because it gives me the error:

> error: Cannot prove that Option[(String, Int)] <:< (T, U).

I was thinking of something like this:

```
val m = list.map(x => x match{case Some(x) => x._1->x._2 
case None => None})
```

but obviously I am missing something :(

Comment: `filter` it. `map` it to a `tuple`. Call `toMap`?

Comment: map it to a tuple it's not what I need. I can't call the toMap (I updated the question to give more insight about this issue). `filter` looks like a good idea, actually. :) I'll give it a try

Comment: You need to [`flatten` out the `Option`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730842/how-to-transform-scala-collection-of-optionx-to-collection-of-x).

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: The problem is that the List type is of Any and not of (String, Int) or Option[(String, Int)]. First make sure the type is correct. Can you not get the tuple into a Some? Then flatten might just work.

Comment: you're right... I actually can make the List as `List[Option[(String,Int))]]`  ...
And then I could do a `flatten` .. Great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
list.collect{case (k,v) => (k,v)}.toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `.flatten` on the list to get only the non-None elements, the do a `.toMap`:

```
list  // : List[Option[(String,Int)]]
  .flatten // : List[(String,Int)]
  .toMap //: Map[String, Int]
```

Comment: `flatten` wouldn't work as the original list isn't `List[Option[(String, Int)]]`.

Comment: The error message implies it is: error: Cannot prove that Option[(String, Int)] <:< (T, U).